# How to get installed pip packages work in python idle?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, python-idle

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and i installed pip through terminal by using command "sudo apt install python3-pip" and i installed colorgram python package through terminal.My problem was i am able to work with colorgram package in terminal but not in python idle.

How to use installed python package in python idle?

Comment: Are you using the same version of IDLE as the version of PIP you installed the package with?

Comment: i am new to it and i donot know how to check it

Comment: There are perhaps 50 questions like this on Stackoverflow.  Try searching a few. The typical reason is having more that one python installation.  Both the standard REPL (run by typing 'python3' in terminal) and IDLE's Shell identify the binary being used at the top.  Something like "Python 3.10.0a7 (tags/v3.10.0a7:53e5529, Apr  6 2021, 10:20:47) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32".